# How to remove fading animation in vertical ViewPager in Android

Tags: android, android-viewpager, scrollview, vertical-scrolling, vertical-scroll

[image]

Above is my issue screenshot. I just want to remove the opacity while I swipe up and down. When I swipe down, the current page turns transparent. I need to remove that transparency. Instead of extending the ViewPager, I have extended the activity. Can anyone give me solution for this issue?

```
public class VerticalViewPager extends Activity  {

private static final float MIN_SCALE = 0.75f;
PagerAdapter adapter;
private static final float MIN_ALPHA = 0.75f;
private boolean a;






@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.verticalviewpager);

    fr.castorflex.android.verticalviewpager.VerticalViewPager verticalViewPager = (fr.castorflex.android.verticalviewpager.VerticalViewPager) findViewById(R.id.verticalviewpager);


    adapter = new MyCustomAdapter(VerticalViewPager.this, SplashScreen.newsidArray, SplashScreen.newsdescArray, SplashScreen.newstitleArray,
            SplashScreen.newsimageArray, SplashScreen.newsdateArray, SplashScreen.newsauthorArray, SplashScreen.newsurlArray);
    verticalViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);
    verticalViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    verticalViewPager.setPageTransformer(false, new PageTransformer() {


        @Override
        public void transformPage(View view, float position) {
            int pageWidth = view.getWidth();
            int pageHeight = view.getHeight();

            if (position <= -1.0F) {
                view.setAlpha(1);
                Log.e("1", "test1");
            } else if (position < 0F) {
                view.setAlpha(1);
                Log.e("2", "test2");
            } else if (position >= 0F) {
                view.setAlpha(0.9F - position);
                view.setTranslationY((int) ((float) (pageHeight) * -position));
                Log.e("3", "test3" + position);
            } else if (position > 1.0F) {
                view.setAlpha(1);
                // view.setTranslationX(position < 0 ? 0f : -pageHeight * position);

                Log.e("4", "test4");
            }


        }
    });


}


}
```

Comment: alpha is going from 0 to 1  -- so set all (view.setAlpha(0);)  to (view.setAlpha(1);)  -- try and see if it helps

Comment: have you tried this android:overScrollMode="never"

Comment: if i change to (view.setAlpha(1);) also same fading animation is occuring

Comment: @Rah ya i tried it is not working for me

Comment: did u get any answer @developer

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.
And you have to confirm not using `setAlpha()` anywhere for page layout.(e.g. layout xml)

```
verticalViewPager.setPageTransformer(false, new ViewPager.PageTransformer() {

        @Override
        public void transformPage(View view, float position) {
            int pageWidth = view.getWidth();
            int pageHeight = view.getHeight();

            if (position >= 0) {
                view.setTranslationY(position < 0 ? 0f : -pageHeight * position);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: i need stacks transformation effect like overlapping the layout

Comment: Have you find any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer, you need to set the background for the view you are animating. By default it is transparent

```
android:background="#FFFFFF"
```